python, celluloid, camera.snap() does not save the actual figure state

The program draws a one-parameter set of straight lines in real time. If I want to save as a gif what the program has output using camera.snap(), then I do not get the desired result. The question is, why does the resulting gif not match the output of the program?
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from celluloid import Camera


def har_1(x, x0):
    return (x - x0)*(1 + np.cos(np.pi*x0/2)**2)/(2*np.cos(np.pi*x0/2))

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
camera = Camera(fig1)

ax1.set_xlim(0,1)
ax1.set_ylim(0,5)
X0 = np.linspace(0, 10)
X = np.linspace(0, 1)


for x0 in X0:
    ax1.plot(X, har_1(X, x0))
    plt.pause(0.1)
    camera.snap()
    


animation = camera.animate()
animation.save('my_animation.gif')


The idea was for the camera to save the frame as I see it when running the program, but it only saves the last added line.

Does this answer your question? Saving an animated Matplotlib graph as a GIF file results in a different looking plot

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation, PillowWriter
import numpy as np

def har_1(x, x0):
    return (x - x0)*(1 + np.cos(np.pi*x0/2)**2)/(2*np.cos(np.pi*x0/2))

X = np.linspace(0, 1)
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

def animate(i):
    ax.clear()
    ax.set_xlim(-25,25)
    ax.set_ylim(-25,25)
    line = ax.plot(X, har_1(X, i), color=f"#{i+100}".ljust(7, '0'))
    return line
        
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=200, blit=True, repeat=True, frames=20)    
ani.save("my_animation.gif", dpi=300, writer=PillowWriter(fps=25))


Thank you, but the question is not how to do it, but why the method used does not give what you want.
